# How to get CPU percentage and memory usage on single line?

Tags: bash

How can I obtain CPU percentage usare and RAM percentage printed out in one line on linux? (Using cli)

I have to pass these output string to an LCD display.

Thx a lot

Answer (score 3):

### Use AWK to Parse Output from Top

```
top -bn1 | awk '/Mem/ { mem = "Memory in Use: " $5 / $3 * 100 "%" };
                /Cpu/ { cpu = "CPU in Use: " 100 - $8 "%" };
                END   { print mem ", " cpu }'
```

This will use top's batch mode to print statistics once, which you can then parse any way you like with awk. For example, the code above yielded this in my test:

> Memory in Use: 93.866%, CPU in Use: 1.7%

Obviously, your output will vary. You can also adjust the output format if you need more (or less) information.

Answer (score 2):

You can parse the output of some of the Unix utilities, such as `vmstat`:

```
$ vmstat
procs -----------memory---------- ---swap-- -----io---- -system-- ----cpu----
 r  b   swpd   free   buff  cache   si   so    bi    bo   in   cs us sy id wa
 1  0  75812 282632 115704 891332    0    1    22    54  138  362 15  2 80  2
$ vmstat | sed -n '3s/ \+/\t/gp' | cut -f5,14
280904  15
```

The above prints the free memory and the CPU usage.

If you want *used* memory, you can use another utility, such as `top` in batch mode, as suggested by CodeGnome and by me in an [earlier answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13180602/1258041).

```
$ top -bn1 | sed -rn '3s/[^0-9]* ([0-9\.]+) .*/\1/p;4s/.*,  ([0-9]+) .*/\1/p' | tr '\n' ' '
10.4 3787340
```

Or to get *percentages*, you can do

```
$ top -bn1 | \
> sed -rn '3s/[^0-9]* ([0-9\.]+) .*/\1/p;4s/[^0-9]*([0-9]+)[^0-9]+([0-9]+) .*/\1 \2/p' | \
> { read cpu; read tot used; echo $cpu $(( 100*used/tot )); }
10.3 94
```

I'm sure there are more elegant solutions though.

Comment: The OP asked for _percentages_.

Comment: @terdon You're right, thanks, I was looking at the title. Updated